# NIR laser reflection from metal surface

Tags: reflection, laser, spectroscopy, infrared-radiation

I am using 980 nm CW diode laser source as excitation source for fluorescence measurement. However, when I try to derive the dark spectrum before fluorescence measurement, I get two different kinds of dark spectrum - (a) when the laser is off, and (b) when the laser is hitting a metal plate without fluorescent sample. For a narrowband laser source (linewidth 10 nm), I expect to get reflection of the laser wavelength only (to verify, I used a 532 nm laser source as well, and got the reflection at only 532 nm). The wavelength range of the spectrometer is 300-900 nm, therefore, I would not see the reflection of my 980 nm laser. But the overall spectrum changes when the laser light is shining on Aluminum metal plate - be it a black or grey. Any other kind of surface would increase the background signal level as well. Using a 900nm longpass filter in front of the laser source does not improve the situation either. [image]

Why does that happen? Why do I have broadband reflection from the surface for a narrowband NIR laser source?

Edit: I have checked power dependency of the background signal as @DavidBailey suggested. It does have an linear effect on background signal level increase.
[image]

Comment: The spectrum in the visible region looks suspiciously like a white LED.  Possibly a fluorescent light bulb, but that's unlikely.  Are there lights on in the room?   In any event, it looks very much like fluorescence from a source around 460 nm.

Comment: What is the power of your laser? Does the the background scale with laser power?

Comment: @garyp Thank you for your comment.  It is indeed the peak from the fluorescent lamp in the lab. I was asking for the background signal level increase. I have indicated these in the figure to avoid confusions like this.

Comment: @DavidBailey The max. power of the laser is 3W. Thank you for your suggestion about checking the power dependency. I have edited my post with the results. The increase in background radiation indeed has an power dependency. But I am still confused about the reason of such phenomenon.

Comment: Can you clarify a few things?  1.)  I don't understand the difference between (a) and (b).  What changes between (a) and (b)?  2) What is the physical arrangement of the sources, samples, and detectors?  3) What is the purpose of the metal plate, and where is it?  4) What do you mean by "metal plate ... wiithout sample?  Is the sample a coating of some sort  on the metal, like paint?   5) There is no feature at 460 nm in the lower, panel.  Are the fluorescent light bulbs on or off?   6) Are there other possible sources in the environment?   I'm also not sure I understand the question.